# Convert list of tuples of several values into dictionary in Python 3.8

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
list = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("a", 2), ("c", 1)]
```

I want to convert it into a dictionary which looks like:

```
{'a': [1, 3, 2], 'b': [2, 1], 'c': [1]}
```

I tried this:

```
for key, value is list:
    if key in list_dictionary:
        dict(list_dictionary)
    else:
        list_dictionary[key] = value
```

and the output came:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is bit different, probably you can checkout this answer too:

```
user_list = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("a", 2), ("c", 1)]

final = {}
for item in user_list:
    final.update(
        {
            item[0]: [item[1]] + final[item[0]] if final.get(item[0]) else [item[1]]
        }
    )
print(final)
```

output: {'a': [2, 3, 1], 'b': [1, 2], 'c': [1]}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your value would be covered.You could use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("a", 2), ("c", 1)]
r = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in l:
    r[key].append(value)

print(r)
```

This gave me:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [1, 3, 2], 'b': [2, 1], 'c': [1]})
```

Answer (score 1):

below

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
 
lst = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("a", 2), ("c", 1)]
for entry in lst:
    data[entry[0]].append(entry[1])
print(data)
```